# Bitcoin - BitGO - Save all wallet objects into Array of Objects

Tags: wallet, nodes, javascript

`My Setup:`
With the help of Mongoose module we handle all Mongo Database operations. 
For each new user a wallet is generated and stored inside a Mongo collection.

`METHOD:`
If we use `User.find({}, function(err, docs) {`. We can get each user object.

```
User.find({}, function(err, docs) {
 if (err) {console.log('Could not find Wallets in DB');} else { 
   docs.forEach(function(address) {
     console.log(address);
   });
 }
});

// console.log(address); <== Result:

{ tokens: [],
  profile: { gender: '', location: '', website: '', picture: '' },
  __v: 0,
  balance: 0,
  playerWallet: '2N3qPHp7bNaL4hiztrzZCzCywryKUzb5aLE',
  password: '$2a$10$JRs/hyiStyhcZzHBwFnhmulKX0vTqlNMTGdxJjDdCSD0Bufe7K6wC',
  email: '111111111111111111111@11111111111111111.com',
  username: '111111111111111111111',
  createdAt: Mon May 02 2016 01:38:11 GMT+0300 (EEST),
  updatedAt: Mon May 02 2016 01:38:17 GMT+0300 (EEST),
  _id: 57268553ea2d6bb50c9d4069 
}
2N3qPHp7bNaL4hiztrzZCzCywryKUzb5aLE }
{ tokens: [],
  profile: { gender: '', location: '', website: '', picture: '' },
  __v: 0,
  balance: 0,
  playerWallet: '2N2oG4nBJZU19Aks3MLvHqDKMXePmHhbEjC',
  password: '$2a$10$cCo5gQgqcRpQW9Dl/Q.48uJEQCaOpJOLY8LVpQxoQFZ6nUqQD8lEC',
  email: '2222222222222222222222222@222222222222222222.com',
  username: '2222222222222222222222222',
  createdAt: Mon May 02 2016 01:38:38 GMT+0300 (EEST),
  updatedAt: Mon May 02 2016 01:38:44 GMT+0300 (EEST),
  _id: 5726856eea2d6bb50c9d406a 
}
2N2oG4nBJZU19Aks3MLvHqDKMXePmHhbEjC
{ tokens: [],
  profile: { gender: '', location: '', website: '', picture: '' },
  __v: 0,
  balance: 0,
  playerWallet: '2My1FGBG6erNXfzeGXg5DXnLk2PWxhpk9SL',
  password: '$2a$10$tL96HqPIAi6q8XnI3z4Bc.dX88fTYQXsTt.UFWJQn4k6ZdDFOZLe2',
  email: '33333333333333333333333@33333333333333333333333.com',
  username: '33333333333333333333333',
  createdAt: Mon May 02 2016 01:39:03 GMT+0300 (EEST),
  updatedAt: Mon May 02 2016 01:39:09 GMT+0300 (EEST),
  _id: 57268587ea2d6bb50c9d406b 
}
```

`HERE LIES THE PROBLEM:`
Because i use a for loop to iterate all wallet addresses, I get 3 different calls and always get one object at a time. I never get more than 1 User object stored into my .JSON file.

```
var _24HourGame = ".24HourGame.json"; // Save Path
var user = 'Super@User.com';
var loginPassword = 'SuperSecretPassword';
var otp = '0000000';

var bitgo = new BitGoJS.BitGo();

var listWallets = function() {

User.find({}, function(err, docs) {
if (err) {console.log('Could not find Wallets in DB');} else { 
  docs.forEach(function(address) {
  console.log(address);
  var allWallets = [];
  allWallets.push(address.playerWallet);

           console.log(allWallets); 
  //   ALL ADDRESSEs EACH IN ITS OWN ARRAY
  //[ '2N3qPHp7bNaL4hiztrzZCzCywryKUzb5aLE' ]
  //[ '2N2oG4nBJZU19Aks3MLvHqDKMXePmHhbEjC' ]
  //[ '2My1FGBG6erNXfzeGXg5DXnLk2PWxhpk9SL' ]

  // Don't know how to use a better method that calls back recursively and sums all 3 obj received into an array....
  for( var iteration in allWallets){ 

        console.log(allWallets[iteration]); 
  //  '2N3qPHp7bNaL4hiztrzZCzCywryKUzb5aLE'
  //  '2N2oG4nBJZU19Aks3MLvHqDKMXePmHhbEjC'
  //  '2My1FGBG6erNXfzeGXg5DXnLk2PWxhpk9SL'

  // How to call a Recursive Callbacks or a Promise for bitgo.wallets().gest({}) while iterating multiple address?
      bitgo.wallets().get({ "id": allWallets[iteration] }, function callback(err, wallet) { 
        if (err) { throw err; }
        console.log( address._id + ' ' + address.playerWallet + ' ' + 'BlockChain_Balance: ' + wallet.balance() / 1e8.toFixed(4) + ' DB_Balance: ' );

        jsonfile.writeFileSync(_24HourGame, wallet, {spaces: 3});

            });
          }

      });
    }
  });

 };

 // Authenticate first
 bitgo.authenticate({ username: user, password: loginPassword, otp: otp }, function(err, result) {
   if (err) { console.dir(err); throw new Error("Could not authenticate!"); }
   console.log("Unlocking account.." );
   bitgo.unlock({ otp: otp }, function(err) {
     if (err) { console.dir(err); throw new Error("Could not unlock!"); }
     listWallets();
     });
 });
```

When i save result to JSON I only get one object at a time:

```
     {
        "_id": "5726858f42929c5c066825b6cc7f9d96",
        "id": "2My1FGBG6erNXfzeGXg5DXnLk2PWxhpk9SL",
        "label": "123labeling",
        "isActive": true,
        "type": "safehd",
        "freeze": {},
        "adminCount": 1,
        "disableTransactionNotifications": false,
        "private": {
           "keychains": [
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcG8zA12U9YnJU3fSxoCq857uMcFon6ViZdYMSeXbeVUGtGkBCasmE3SGdJVRr4ui1V8TzsmM7K6eKikSi9gZQiJXoVumGTnU",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "031ec65814f7e46e274a78671f6ed2b945c386e378160b19613ce8ba555e793635",
                    "chainCode": "a046f6f6ea9fd06974b333e87a483c9c3cbdeb41c0e56c8f21a6954f9f95e387",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub6GiRC55CRvMEnS2CtwqrMNKDnpsogbX1tukjM2xWyW1PttVLSEVgDiJq7bWh6esAQWeQ9oGNR56RHqwzKLCzzneM6DGq91v8sA9DAJbUbtm",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "027f30812a8f33ffeb44515d0fe9cc99041c2369f407ecc537d492d34da48c29d2",
                    "chainCode": "4f493067187019f78a773e3e559c699b98c0e82a53cbf76cf9ba5db8103062a0",
                    "depth": 5,
                    "index": 58402,
                    "parentFingerprint": 2966462100
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcF6cBQfmTER34dwShTVu6x2h24nxhHxMX3jAHCP9DJYuLcHABvaMeaBcSMdcte8mhAMnCcBCypK5iGe6H33aUH8JWbstSKP9",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "02ec33597217f00f1ad5689b0abbfd01d850c921d4560d1333f52f9f70eea2aafd",
                    "chainCode": "37b746ccdf38587d6a943f8007ef9e3012f52c73079f53c094f446cd43f9bb4f",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              }
           ]
        },
        "canSendInstant": true,
        "permissions": "admin,spend,view",
        "admin": {
           "users": [
              {
                 "user": "56f9e3b2cd8f2e5906530948fe1af2d2",
                 "permissions": "admin,spend,view"
              }
           ]
        },
        "tags": [],
        "approvalsRequired": 1,
        "spendingAccount": true,
        "pendingApprovals": [],
        "balance": 30000000,
        "instantBalance": 0,
        "spendableConfirmedBalance": 0,
        "confirmedBalance": 0,
        "spendableBalance": 0,
        "sent": 0,
        "received": 30000000,
        "unconfirmedSends": 0,
        "unconfirmedReceives": 30000000
     }
```

I want to sum all objects into one array of objects...:

```
     [
     {
        "_id": "5726857642929c5c066825819a872925",
        "id": "2N2oG4nBJZU19Aks3MLvHqDKMXePmHhbEjC",
        "label": "123labeling",
        "isActive": true,
        "type": "safehd",
        "freeze": {},
        "adminCount": 1,
        "disableTransactionNotifications": false,
        "private": {
           "keychains": [
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcH2AHKRsNyEv4euymBzY8P52NzeodZBBvG8zPtpLeEJmjD8xevZRrDLCyCr4TjmavB9TuAw69bDH3TkKNPyEQ2UBVrGg8uVq",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "038c20add130bf5d79fc1debc658e8866f5c69962efc15350941d18cc3b88c025f",
                    "chainCode": "f8e61f519f8e5363b24fe19912a25c90395a9189f59517d5c888c2b2eaefe4ba",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub6GiRC55CRvMEkcMvj2xtGSMhQzAys7EMV4gvqporNz5kSkzuqt3x25cnpvYWyR24y38WYij7eLr3xSQsBo7TBHWR27b5QZTrj5sVq5MMBVa",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "037e26f5594705a05a49e63dbd7eb98e0fb56d0f26b584c8e4fcdb15efd0239d62",
                    "chainCode": "984f19d3ae866a97a1b3a0bad1abf2a9aa77dbf50465180dee0cf8a8b73089c8",
                    "depth": 5,
                    "index": 58401,
                    "parentFingerprint": 2966462100
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcGdVpPbFpvi37Ziteqj4JY3uEoV6XijMAk62Pgs2jK3bRPPVjKg4AtwbZ6xiMMHD56oHCdGQwqtWNZgwSWefw9edex9aJ9KC",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "03b323e0b6ebb0cbb845be13c5a090c4648de18c090382e899e66c389c0f6451fc",
                    "chainCode": "d1a6e364a4b44764190148e725a8c584583743d31df2d06439b70016e19799b5",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              }
           ]
        },
        "canSendInstant": true,
        "permissions": "admin,spend,view",
        "admin": {
           "users": [
              {
                 "user": "56f9e3b2cd8f2e5906530948fe1af2d2",
                 "permissions": "admin,spend,view"
              }
           ]
        },
        "tags": [],
        "approvalsRequired": 1,
        "spendingAccount": true,
        "pendingApprovals": [],
        "balance": 533000000,
        "instantBalance": 0,
        "spendableConfirmedBalance": 0,
        "confirmedBalance": 0,
        "spendableBalance": 0,
        "sent": 0,
        "received": 533000000,
        "unconfirmedSends": 0,
        "unconfirmedReceives": 533000000
     },
     {
        "_id": "5726858f42929c5c066825b6cc7f9d96",
        "id": "2My1FGBG6erNXfzeGXg5DXnLk2PWxhpk9SL",
        "label": "123labeling",
        "isActive": true,
        "type": "safehd",
        "freeze": {},
        "adminCount": 1,
        "disableTransactionNotifications": false,
        "private": {
           "keychains": [
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcG8zA12U9YnJU3fSxoCq857uMcFon6ViZdYMSeXbeVUGtGkBCasmE3SGdJVRr4ui1V8TzsmM7K6eKikSi9gZQiJXoVumGTnU",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "031ec65814f7e46e274a78671f6ed2b945c386e378160b19613ce8ba555e793635",
                    "chainCode": "a046f6f6ea9fd06974b333e87a483c9c3cbdeb41c0e56c8f21a6954f9f95e387",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub6GiRC55CRvMEnS2CtwqrMNKDnpsogbX1tukjM2xWyW1PttVLSEVgDiJq7bWh6esAQWeQ9oGNR56RHqwzKLCzzneM6DGq91v8sA9DAJbUbtm",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "027f30812a8f33ffeb44515d0fe9cc99041c2369f407ecc537d492d34da48c29d2",
                    "chainCode": "4f493067187019f78a773e3e559c699b98c0e82a53cbf76cf9ba5db8103062a0",
                    "depth": 5,
                    "index": 58402,
                    "parentFingerprint": 2966462100
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcF6cBQfmTER34dwShTVu6x2h24nxhHxMX3jAHCP9DJYuLcHABvaMeaBcSMdcte8mhAMnCcBCypK5iGe6H33aUH8JWbstSKP9",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "02ec33597217f00f1ad5689b0abbfd01d850c921d4560d1333f52f9f70eea2aafd",
                    "chainCode": "37b746ccdf38587d6a943f8007ef9e3012f52c73079f53c094f446cd43f9bb4f",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              }
           ]
        },
        "canSendInstant": true,
        "permissions": "admin,spend,view",
        "admin": {
           "users": [
              {
                 "user": "56f9e3b2cd8f2e5906530948fe1af2d2",
                 "permissions": "admin,spend,view"
              }
           ]
        },
        "tags": [],
        "approvalsRequired": 1,
        "spendingAccount": true,
        "pendingApprovals": [],
        "balance": 30000000,
        "instantBalance": 0,
        "spendableConfirmedBalance": 0,
        "confirmedBalance": 0,
        "spendableBalance": 0,
        "sent": 0,
        "received": 30000000,
        "unconfirmedSends": 0,
        "unconfirmedReceives": 30000000
     },
     {
        "_id": "5726855c0cb29c5b060918484524d6d9",
        "id": "2N3qPHp7bNaL4hiztrzZCzCywryKUzb5aLE",
        "label": "123labeling",
        "isActive": true,
        "type": "safehd",
        "freeze": {},
        "adminCount": 1,
        "disableTransactionNotifications": false,
        "private": {
           "keychains": [
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcFcyTCTTNVmYcAmPJ2yRJanFPv9To7n1wk5cZmgUpzY16pAz9m6XriziHnk6c4Y2Hov9HJSmWPSHdmSLn9KNBLMr5Qi29HGN",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "032536e93aa4cd5feb0706d118b6ecf695d26544c00f92a2fb36ef9208ee216821",
                    "chainCode": "6c4dbaed05b8a09d2d64c3688e3fb53f12e62ef64b70ad808a700830e2063bb2",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub6GiRC55CRvMEhQVtxhHwwpmG7NVyjT1SUuyYXfafsRDW4XoYRwzPp6Af5vY83hLN8vaFCzk9FdtUqdeXoQbS7fXNJU3eFYPnU1bfkjimsT4",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "035d12105eab700c637ca9fbbea066beca88c6603f90f98c07a9e5b84713d6ff20",
                    "chainCode": "5670e6ede3379f33cc635981c7fbe9255c3f69a5e4868e5491e42bf3d5fb380a",
                    "depth": 5,
                    "index": 58400,
                    "parentFingerprint": 2966462100
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcEZBgr8PUbKfGBaQ98GFp2wGdR6vDwTAzruGenMnn3PqDo9MMmzSsF8dFWgUfUUV1Yor2ErVrohBNHj9Ug81ih7VAohfnEQu",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "024f7b2f85a3e0b859c4bdb975f9953973de4806300b2148afec66fb610af380a7",
                    "chainCode": "014ce166076a6045fb5a88fa4a51052d13c5449a4367d030e0f6bc058a9d0191",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              }
           ]
        },
        "canSendInstant": true,
        "permissions": "admin,spend,view",
        "admin": {
           "users": [
              {
                 "user": "56f9e3b2cd8f2e5906530948fe1af2d2",
                 "permissions": "admin,spend,view"
              }
           ]
        },
        "tags": [],
        "approvalsRequired": 1,
        "spendingAccount": true,
        "pendingApprovals": [],
        "balance": 330000000,
        "instantBalance": 0,
        "spendableConfirmedBalance": 0,
        "confirmedBalance": 0,
        "spendableBalance": 0,
        "sent": 0,
        "received": 330000000,
        "unconfirmedSends": 0,
        "unconfirmedReceives": 330000000
     }
     ]
```

Hoping that someone has done something like this and can easily spot the error.

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, didn't push wallet results...

Here is the working code:

```
  var bitgo = new BitGoJS.BitGo();

  var listWallets = function() {

  User.find({}, function(err, docs) {
  if (err) {console.log('Could not find Wallets in DB');} else { 
    var allWallets = [];
    var allTXS = [];

  docs.forEach(function(address) {
    // console.log(address);
    allWallets.push(address.playerWallet);
  });

             console.log(allWallets); 
    //   ALL ADDRESSEs EACH IN ITS OWN ARRAY
    //[ '2N3qPHp7bNaL4hiztrzZCzCywryKUzb5aLE' ]
    //[ '2N2oG4nBJZU19Aks3MLvHqDKMXePmHhbEjC' ]
    //[ '2My1FGBG6erNXfzeGXg5DXnLk2PWxhpk9SL' ]

    // Don't know how to use a better method that calls back recursively and sums all 3 obj received into an array....
    for( var iteration in allWallets){ 

          // console.log(allWallets[iteration]); 
    //  '2N3qPHp7bNaL4hiztrzZCzCywryKUzb5aLE'
    //  '2N2oG4nBJZU19Aks3MLvHqDKMXePmHhbEjC'
    //  '2My1FGBG6erNXfzeGXg5DXnLk2PWxhpk9SL'

    // How to call a Recursive Callbacks or a Promise for bitgo.wallets().gest({}) while iterating multiple address?
        bitgo.wallets().get({ "id": allWallets[iteration] }, function callback(err, wallet) { 
          if (err) { throw err; }
          // console.log( address._id + ' ' + address.playerWallet + ' ' + 'BlockChain_Balance: ' + wallet.balance() / 1e8.toFixed(4) + ' DB_Balance: ' );
          allTXS.push(wallet);

          jsonfile.writeFileSync(_24HourGame, allTXS, {spaces: 3});
              });
            }

      }
    });

   };

   // Authenticate first
   bitgo.authenticate({ username: user, password: loginPassword, otp: otp }, function(err, result) {
     if (err) { console.dir(err); throw new Error("Could not authenticate!"); }
     console.log("Unlocking account.." );
     bitgo.unlock({ otp: otp }, function(err) {
       if (err) { console.dir(err); throw new Error("Could not unlock!"); }
       listWallets();
       });
   });
```

Thank you for your help !